# Windows NDIS FilterDriver object IO access for non-admin processes

Tags: wdk, windows-kernel, ndis

I have Windows NDIS FilterDriver and it has name `\\Device\\MyFilter`.
User application performs some DeviceIoControl operation with the FilterDriver and calls following code to open the device handle:

```
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
DWORD   CreationDistribution = OPEN_EXISTING;
DWORD   FlagsAndAttributes = FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;
DWORD   DesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
DWORD   ShareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
DWORD   lastErr = 0;

m_hFilter = CreateFileA(MY_FILTER_NAME, /* "\\\\.\\\\MyFilter" */
    DesiredAccess, ShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, CreationDistribution, FlagsAndAttributes, NULL);

if (m_hFilter == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    lastErr = GetLastError();
    return false;
}
```

It works great if user application was run "As Administrator", otherwise (if run as regular User) CreateFileA returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, and lastErr = 5 (Access Denied)

Reasons why it returns "Access Denied" are clear.
How to make user's application to open the Filter Driver object?

The idea of creating an interface with IoRegisterDeviceInterface() looks promising, but it requires the pointer to PDO, which I do not know where to obtain for NDIS Filter.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultSDDLString field of the NDIS_DEVICE_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES argument should be properly set for call of NdisRegisterDeviceEx()

```
//...
DeviceAttribute.DefaultSDDLString = &SDDL_DEVOBJ_SYS_ALL_ADM_RWX_WORLD_RWX_RES_RWX;
// Register the filter driver
Status = NdisRegisterDeviceEx(g_FHandle, &DeviceAttribute, &g_Object, &g_Handle);
```

Thanks, Scott_Noone_(OSR)!